# how to upgrade gearman server on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt

I am completely new to Linux/Ubuntu and command-line. At work I needed to install gearman server and workers on an Ubuntu 11.10 Rackspace box. I ran this command `apt-get install gearman-job-server` to install the server but it installed version 0.14 which is outdated from many years ago. Is there a way I can just upgrade the package to the latest via command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each version of Ubuntu has a fixed set of packages and only minor version updates are provided by default package updater. Default `apt-get` can not install newer major version, to use the latest version, you must install it manually.

To manually install gearman-job-server, you can either compile and install it from source ([instructions](http://gearman.org/getting_started#compile_and_install_from_tarball)) or use the ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gearman-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gearman-job-server gearman-tools
```

but remeber to remove the old version first:

```
sudo apt-get remove gearman-job-server
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to get everything working.

Comment: You may also need libgearman-dev if you want to install pecl extension for PHP